# How to share PHAsset by using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller, phasset

I'm now trying to share Phasset (video or image) through UIActivityViewController.

AFAIK I used to share image or video located in my document directory by giving url to array and using like this

```
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:m_arryContents applicationActivities:nil];
```

But I have no idea how could I share phasset.

**I want to share phasset without downloading or exporting to my document folder.**

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try my code or do you have questions about it? - When I got you right, this code I'm using, does exactly share multiple PHAssets (or to be exact the images the PHAssets are representing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the following method:

```
NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

NSMutableArray *activityItems = [NSMutableArray array];

// image Loader
PHImageManager *im = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.synchronous = YES;
options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeOpportunistic;
options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeNone;

for (NSIndexPath *index in selectedIndexPaths)
{
    // load image
    [im requestImageDataForAsset:self.assetsFetchResults[index.item] options:options resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info)
     {
         [activityItems addObject:imageData];
     }];
}

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
// prevent sharing to gallery again
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
```

First I tried to use the NSURL to the file, but this does not work with every share-extension (e.g. mail did not work, but imessage did...)
So I ended up, sharing the NSData of the images.

Note:
self.assetsFetchResults is an PHFetchResults used here like a simple NSArray by accessing the PHAssets I like to share.

Note2:
I only have local images in me PHFetchResults!

Comment: Right. For the images, it would work and good way but if videos in the list then we need exporting to share. Right?

Comment: yes, I think so. Sharing the NSURL to the original, did not work as expected :(

Answer (score -1):

For now I can't find any solution for this.
Ricoh theta and GoPro gallery also not provides multi-sharing for this reason. Maybe Apple only allows multi-sharing only for their gallery.

If anyone find the solution please share me. Thanks.